# How to disable Files and Folders permissions for specific apps on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos

I am trying to establish a secure folder in macOS Sonoma 14.3 which should be only accessible to applications with explicitly granted permissions. As far as I understand, this can be only done for certain folders (Documents, Downloads...) so I would need to use one of these folders.

I have tested this solution on "Downloads folder" with DataSpell app. I have removed permission for DataSpell to access Downloads in Settings > Privacy & Security > Files and Folders. When I try to open a file in Downloads using DataSpell, I receive the following warning message as expected:

> DataSpell.app would like to access files in your Downloads folder.

However, the file opens normally even when I choose to deny this permission. In Files and Folders setting, permission is set to disabled.

Am I misunderstanding how this feature is supposed to work or is there anything else I need to do to make it work as expected?

Comment: Which other permissions does the application have? Also, I assume you are aware that the protection only works against applications, not Finder or a shell running in Terminal?